# For a Win32 Desktop C application, what is the best way to display messages when a program is ending

Tags: c, winapi, desktop-application, win32-process

As an exercise, I'm trying to write a 100% correct Windows program.  To that end, I'm checking the return values of every Win32 API call I use and report to the user if there are any problems.

This generally works fine until the program starts to close... for example:

```
      case WM_CLOSE:
         {
            MessageBoxA( NULL, "Foo", "Testing", MB_OK );
            DestroyWindow( hWnd );
            MessageBoxA( NULL, "Bar", "Testing", MB_OK );

            break;
```

Displays `Foo` but not `Bar`.  I've observed that any `MessageBox` after `DestroyWindow` will not render.

I understand the technical reasons for this... My question for StackOverflow is:  In a Win32 Desktop C program, what is the best mechanism/design to inform the user about something (`Boo`, `Program ended successfully`, whatever...) at the end of the program?

Ideally, I'd like to be able to display a `MessageBox` just before `wWinMain` terminates.

Thank you!

Comment: The best way is to not bother the user. Just exit the program.

Comment: The user knows the program ended successfully if they choose to close the application and it closes. I'd find any message that was displayed to tell me something obvious and useless really annoying, probably to the point of looking for a different app that didn't irritate me so much.

Comment: Cheatah & Ken:  Normally, I'd agree.  I hate routine/annoying messages as well.  This is specifically for error messages, I just omitted that bit as I wanted to make my question as generic as possible.  If everything is working correctly, the program just ends - but if there's any problems during shutdown, I want to inform the user.

Comment: A message box is pretty much _never_ the best way to inform the user about something, in any given scenario. It ought to be one of most poorly considered inventions in the history of GUI programming. In particular: what if the user's finger is already rapidly approaching enter at the moment of time when the program decides to spew a message box?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I've observed that any `MessageBox` after `DestroyWindow` will not render.

Without seeing the rest of your code, I would guess that you are handling `WM_DESTROY` to call `PostQuitMessage()`.

If so, then `WM_DESTROY` will be processed while `DestroyWindow()` is still running, thus `WM_QUIT` will be posted before the 2nd call to `MessageBox()` is made.

The internal message loop inside of `MessageBox()` will thus pick up the `WM_QUIT` message and discard its dialog window.  And, being a good modal dialog function, `MessageBox()` will [re-post the `WM_QUIT` message](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050222-00/?p=36393) so that other message loops higher up on the call stack (like yours) will still be able to exit correctly, thus letting your app terminate correctly.

> Ideally, I'd like to be able to display a MessageBox just before wWinMain terminates.

So, what is stopping you from doing so? Simply do it after your message loop has already handled the `WM_QUIT` message, eg:

```
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nShowCmd)
{
    ...
    MSG msg;
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    ...
    MessageBox(...); // <-- here
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Remy,  Thank you.  That was lame on my part (I had a feeling I was missing something obvious -- and I was).